# Check whether ALL missing values have the same value in another column in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
x    y
0    ny
21   ch
NaN  ap
21   ca
NaN  ap
```

All missing values (`NaN`) in the column `x` should have the value `ap` in the column `y`. How can I check whether this is true? I'm looking for a line of code that performs this check automatically, and returns `True` or `False`.

EDIT: This question was closed and marked as duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737207/check-whether-all-nan-values-have-a-certain-value-in-a-different-columns-in-a-pa). But the suggested answer isn't at all relevant to what I'm asking here. Hence, I've asked the question again.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: The expected output is just `True` or `False`

Comment: So if first value is `NaN` then False? An solution shoud return True?

Comment: If first `NaN` is `0` ouput is `False` ?

Comment: So the code should check whether ALL rows of `x` that are `NaN` are `ap` in `y`. If ANY `NaN` is `0` for example, this should return `False` :)

Answer (score 3):

If need test if missing values has only `NaN`s filter first all misng rows by `x` and then test if all values `y` are `ap`:

```
test = df.loc[df['x'].isna(), 'y'].eq('ap').all()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to filter your dataframe to check the remaining values.
Assuming your dataframe name is `df`, you can try this.

```
verify_df = df.loc[(df['x'] == NaN) & (df['y'] == 'ap')]
verify_df
```